# Exception loading Facebook Login Button in Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to make an app with facebook integration. I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0. I'm able to import the facebook skd 4.0.0 in build.gradle (Module:app) and use it in the Java code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

I also put the LoginButton into the layout file from my activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This [exception](http://pastebin.com/Gyxv4HPN) is thrown at `setContentView(layoutfile)`.

I already checked the samples in facebook sdk on github but it doesn't helped me to fix this problem. Is the import of facebook sdk correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize in your Activity or Application onCreate.

Comment: I called the FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(..) after setContentView(..). I should call it before ;)

Answer (score 0):

check the menifest.xml at  
I used facebookSDK 3.x and I upgrade 4.x.
I have your similar situation. and I change this "provider.." at menifest.xml. 
And I solve the problem. "provider .."source of 4.x is different. This change is at developers.facebook.com (upgrade 3.x -> 4.x page) .